# json_encode arrays with iso-8895 characters

Tags: php, json, encoding

I have a quite complex, even though not really big, array, with many levels of nesting.
The array contains values that are encoded in ISO-8895, and also objects, with the same issue.
If I just

```
 json_encode($array)
```

PHP wil silently encode all the values contining ISO-8895 characters as `null`.

Looking at the PHP documentation, I managed to write a working solution:

```
function fixMultibyteSerializedObject($match)
{
    return 's:' . mb_strlen($match[2]);
}
/**
 * Useful to json-encode arrays of objects with ISO-8895 encoded values.
 * Does not work with iso-encoded keys
 * @param var $object array or object to be encoded
 * @param int $options json_encode options
 */
function isoJsonEncode($object, $options = null)
{
    $str = serialize($object);
    $str = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'utf-8');
    $str = preg_replace_callback(
            '!(?<=^|;)s:(\d+)(?=:"(.*?)";(?:}|a:|s:|b:|d:|i:|o:|N;))!s',
             'fixMultibyteSerializedObject',
            $str);
    $object = unserialize($str);
    return json_encode($object, $options);
}
```

Apart from getting a better library, such as the Zend json encoding component, can you suggest a better solution?

Thank you,
   Iacopo

Comment: Do you *require* the encoded array to contain ISO-8895 characters? Otherwise a simple conversion to UTF-8 seems the best solution.

Comment: The encoded array comes from outside my control. They _are_ ISO encoded. I just don't want to recursively scan the array's values

Comment: @lacopo: You may want to consider converting the input to UTF-8 (using `iconv`, like in [deceze's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830054/json-encode-arrays-with-iso-8895-characters/6830949#6830949)) rather than on output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
array_walk_recursive($array, function (&$elem) {
    if (is_string($elem)) {
        $elem = iconv('ISO-8895', 'UTF-8', $elem);
    }
});

echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: I like it, but what if the target is an object and not an array? (I edited the question to include objects)

Comment: @lacopo Then you can iterate the object properties using `foreach`. If you have *nested* objects or objects with array properties then well, the code will get a little more complicated. Overall though, using UTF-8 is the least headache inducing method you can choose. Always. Unless you specifically require a different encoding.

Comment: Thank you: actually I had to write 10 lines of code more, but now it is something like 20 times faster :-)   P.S. Well, I know having all in UTF-8 is better, but a 10-years old entreprise Oracle Db in ISO-8895 is quite a good reason to sitck with that encoding